# Can't find Localizations in Info in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization

I was following an example of localization in a book for learning iOS development. The books instructs me to add a non-English language, e.g. Finish, by clicking the Plus button under Localizations. The book doesn't say where I can find Localizations. I searched through Google and  an Apple Developer Document (ADD) webpage shows it under Info in the project editing page.

When I went to the Info pane for my project (an example project from the abovementioned book) on the Xcode (Verions 10.1) I'm using, I couldn't see the Localizations item on the Info pane as I had previously seen on the ADD page. I continued my search on the Internet and found an Apple WWDC 2018 video for showcasing the New Localization Workflows in Xcode 10. In that vidwo, I saw the presenter show how to add a non-English language to a project for localization in Xcode (Version 10.0). I could see the Localizations item in the Info pane of her demo project.

So, I wonder what configurations I could've possibly missed out when I started my example project. Would you please give me some guide to adding Localizations to the Info pane of my project?

Thank you very much!

Attachment: a screenshot of the Info pane of my project:
[image]

Comment: Go to `General` tab instead, on left of `Capabilities` tab

Comment: Thanks, @ReinierMelian. I had done that before I posted this question. In fact, I had scrambled through all the tabs in the project editing pane. But I hadn't been able to find the Localizations item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows that you are on the settings page for your *target* (red arrow), you need to go to the page for your *project* (green arrow), then go to "Info" and press the plus button (blue circle).

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Sweeper, for your picture that aided me in making clear the difference between the settings for a project and its corresponding target. As one new to iOS development, I'm still getting myself acquainted with Xcode. I now know I need to expand the window beside the navigation area to look at the settings of a project.

Answer (score 1):

Expand your inspector. Here you'll find out your Localize... button.

[image]

After that create your string file and name it as localized.

[image]

Finally, select the project and add a new language.

[image]

Comment: OP is trying to add a non-English _localisation_ to their project. Pressing the Localise button localises the file, but does not add a new localisation. OP will not be able to select a non-English localisation if they have not added any into their project yet.

Comment: follow this link https://medium.com/lean-localization/ios-localization-tutorial-938231f9f881

Comment: Thank you, @AMIT, for your suggested solution and recommended reading. Although Sweeper's solution directly helped solve my problem, your illustrated explanation and the Medium article provided more detailed information which facilitated my understanding of the matter localization in iOS development.